# Difference between connection, client and db in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I am creating a connection to a database in `mongoose` as follows

```js
// CONNECTION to Mongo without database name. Eg DATABASE_URL=mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/
const connection = await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

// GET CLIENT
var dbClient = connection.connections[0].client;
    
// GET DATABASE. Eg. DATABASE=Questions
db = dbClient.db(process.env.DATABASE);
```

What is the difference between `connection`, `dbClient`. I think I understand that `database` represents?

If I create a `model` and call `save` on it, how do I tell `mongoose` to save in a collection in `DATABASE`?

```js
const Question = mongoose.model("Question", questionSchema);
module.exports = Question;

...

q = Question({
  description: "some description",
  hints: ["hint1", "hint2"],
  topic: 'area'
});

await q.save()
```

Comment: I posted an answer, but I strongly advise you to read the getting started for mongoose: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power of mongoose is that *a lot* is done for you.
You don't ever need to access the `database`, `connection`, nor the `dbClient`.

By doing `await q.save()`, you already tell mongoose to save the `q` document you created.

And it knows where to save it because you declared `Question` as a `model` with a `schema`:

```js
mongoose.model("Question", questionSchema)
```

At startup, mongoose should have created the `Question` collection for you.

You should see this collection with 1 document appear in [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/tools/compass).

---

**Update:** I think you are mixing databases and collections.

One database should be per environment, like prod, staging, dev, etc.

Accessing multiple databases in the same application is a dark pattern. The connection string should contain the database, and be an environment variable:

```
DATABASE_URL=mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/<your-database-name>
```

Generally, databases are named `<application-name>-<environment>`.

If you have multiple types of questions, you should create multiple collections in your database:

- Database: `<application-name>-<environment>`

  - Collection 1: `questions-areas`
  - Collection 2: `questions-<name 2>`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. For this to work, I should be connected to the right database when calling `connect`. I am looking for flexibility that I don't connect to a specific database and switch between databases.

Comment: I strongly believe you shouldn't have an application which connects to multiple databases. What is your use case? Why can't you just do multiple collections? Generally, you should have 1 database per environment (e.g. prod, staging, etc.)