# clarity regarding mongoose documentation - connect returning connection array

Tags: mongoose

I am using `mongoose` and referring to api https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html

My `package.json` says `"mongoose": "^7.4.0"` so I am not sure which specific version I am on. Assuming it is `7.5.0`, I am using `connect` call to connect to `mongodb` via `mongoose`

```
const connection = await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
          var localdbClient = connection.connections[0].client;
```

I can't find where in the document it says that `connection` has `connections` `array`. Where is it mentioned? Is the type of `connection[]` a `connection`? This doesn't say so - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html

How should I refer to the `api` and `definitions`?

Comment: Tip: if you are using `yarn`, you can use `yarn why mongoose` to know which exact version you are using. Otherwise, just look in your lock file. If you don't have a lock file, you can look directly in `node_modules/mongoose/package.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connections` array is documented here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#Mongoose.prototype.connections

But apparently, what you really want here is `getClient()`:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#Connection.prototype.getClient()

Comment: I had asked a question previously to understand the differences between different objects in `mongoose` but didn't get an answer. Would you be able to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76942968/difference-between-connection-client-and-db-in-mongoose ?